What am i doing wrong? Solders library doesn't work correctly
import base58
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.rpc.api import Client as SolanaClient
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solders.instruction import Instruction
from solders.account import Account
from solders.hash import Hash
from solders.message import Message
Constants
RPC_ENDPOINT = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
PRIVATE_KEY = "your_base58_private_key_here"  # Replace with your actual base58 private key
CANDY_MACHINE_ADDRESS = "5SyzXm1zvjSPErYfPuezonr6Sbai3TCcyc2Fk7VoHGq6"  # Replace with actual Candy Machine address
PROGRAM_ID = "F9SixdqdmEBP5kprp2gZPZNeMmfHJRCTMFjN22dx3akf"  # Replace with actual Program ID
Initialize Solana RPC client
client = SolanaClient(RPC_ENDPOINT)
Decode the private key and set up the payer Keypair
payer = Keypair.from_bytes(base58.b58decode(PRIVATE_KEY))
candy_machine_pubkey = Pubkey.from_string(CANDY_MACHINE_ADDRESS)
program_id_pubkey = Pubkey.from_string(PROGRAM_ID)
Function to fetch the latest blockhash
def get_latest_blockhash():
response = client.get_latest_blockhash()
if not response.value:  # Check if the blockhash value is valid
raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch blockhash: {response}")
return response.value.blockhash  # Correctly access blockhash here
Function to get Candy Machine data (Account info)
def get_candy_machine_data():
response = client.get_account_info(candy_machine_pubkey)
if not response.value:  # No data found for this account
raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch Candy Machine data: {response}")
account_info = response.value
if not account_info.data:  # If data is empty or missing
raise Exception("Candy Machine data is missing.")
# Debug: print the raw data of the Candy Machine account to understand its structure
print("Raw Candy Machine Data:", account_info.data)

# Handle different types of data (assume it is base58 or raw data)
try:
    # Try decoding base58 data (if it's base58-encoded)
    decoded_data = base58.b58decode(account_info.data)
    print("Decoded Candy Machine Data:", decoded_data)
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(f"Failed to decode Candy Machine data: {e}")

return decoded_data

Function to create and send the minting transaction
def mint_nft():
blockhash = get_latest_blockhash()  # Get the latest blockhash
candy_machine_data = get_candy_machine_data()  # Get Candy Machine state
# Create a new mint account (NFT address)
new_mint = Keypair()

# Build the minting transaction
transaction = Transaction(recent_blockhash=blockhash)

# Add accounts to the transaction
payer_account = Account(pubkey=payer.pubkey())  # Construct Account using the payer's public key
candy_machine_account = Account(pubkey=candy_machine_pubkey)  # Construct Account for Candy Machine

# Create the Mint Instruction for the Candy Machine
mint_instruction = Instruction(
    program_id=program_id_pubkey,
    accounts=[payer_account, candy_machine_account],  # Pass Account objects directly here
    data=candy_machine_data  # Use the state data to pass the minting information
)

transaction.add(mint_instruction)

# Send the transaction
response = client.send_transaction(transaction, payer)
if response['result'].get('error'):  # Check if there was an error in the response
    raise Exception(f"Failed to send transaction: {response['result']['error']}")

return response

Call the minting function
try:
result = mint_nft()
print("Minting successful:", result)
except Exception as e:
print(f"Error: {e}")
THE ERROR:
Raw Candy Machine Data: b"l,\xf9\xbe\x15\x12\x1b\x7f\xfbYrl\xf9\x86$\xa4\xe2\x87\x01\x995\x19\x8bka\xcc2c\xcac4\xcd\xd5\xa4\x07n\x80#\xb3\x99&\x12:\xfc\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00G%\xbe^\xc0+\xbb\x03,\x02\xf0\x1c@\xbb!\xb9\xb4o\x95\xb8|&\xb1\x82d>\xf1N\x05H\x1a\xe8\x01\x0b\x00\x00\x00NIGGARDIO #L\x00\x00\x00https://gateway.pinit.io/ipfs/QmQwSsJZxzzNzNiLenLrhbsoehHgFnTP3joMYWuJx44q6b\t\x00\x00\x00NIGGARDIO\x02\x00\x00\x00G%\xbe^\xc0+\xbb\x03,\x02\xf0\x1c@\xbb!\xb9\xb4o\x95\xb8|&\xb1\x82d>\xf1N\x05H\x1a\xe8Z\xcf\x88?\xa8\xaa\x0f:\n'P\xcfD\x06\x0e#%\xa5w\x13IQ\x8d$\x0b\xe5x\x10F\xa23U\x9c\n+\x02W\x04\x00\x00H\x01\x00\x00\x008e\xa5\x7f]\x8d\x1c\xca\xbf\xa7\xaf\xaa_\x83\x83\xd1\xb5c'\x93p\xe3\xf2\xdd?\xb1\xd7\xf47-\x01\x01\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00v\x978g\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x01\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01X\x02\x00\x00H\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00Public\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00G%\xbe^\xc0+\xbb\x03,\x02\xf0\x1c@\xbb!\xb9\xb4o\x95\xb8|&\xb1\x82d>\xf1N\x05H\x1a\xe8Z\xcf\x88?\xa8\xaa\x0f:\n'P\xcfD\x06\x0e#%\xa5w\x13IQ\x8d$\x0b\xe5x\x10F\xa23U\x9c\n"
Error: Failed to decode Candy Machine data: Invalid character 'l'
